# Change the state of a relation in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, ef-model-first

My question is directly in relation to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4365552/607162).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367057/607162) says "You also have to change state of the relation".

I use Model-First approach, and I don't have the foreign key in my entity. I only have the navigation property.

I Can change the state of the entities via `DbEntityEntry`, but I can't figure how to change the state of the *relation* itself. How can I access it?

Exemple of my code :

```
Building building = new Building() { Id = 1, Name = "modified" }; //Buiding 1 exists in DB
building.Adress = new Adress() { Id = 1, Road = "Sesame street" }; //Address 1 exists in DB
building.Adress.State = new State() { Id = 1 }; //State with Id 1 exists in DB

dbContext.Entry<Building>(building).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry<Adress>(building.Adress).State = EntityState.Modified;
//The state itself is not modified, but the relation between adress and state may do.
dbContext.Entry<State>(building.Adress.State).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This code pass without error, but the relation between `Adress` and `State` is never updated.
The `Name` of the building and the `Street` properties does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ObjectStatementManager (and use ctrl + . to get the references for IObjectContextAdapter).

```
var unchangedItems = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged);
var addedItems = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
```

It also specifically has `ChangeRelationshipState` which sounds appropriate in your scenario.

Comment: `ChangeRelationshipState` is not available in .NET Core, unfortunately.